# Connect as specific user at Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

This is a home network with all Win7 clients and HomeGroup setup. I can RDC to my laptop as that workstation's primary, original Admin account. I've added a 2nd (also admin) account and would like that account to be used by RDC connections but every new connection is as that original account.

If I leave the secondary account logged in, then go to my other workstation to initiate the RDC, I'm informed 'another user is logged in, if you continue that user will be disconnected.'

I know of a number of alternatives for remote access - I'm trying to get the native windows version to work.

thx

EDIT: My original wording has lead the two current answers to think i'm talking about 2 remote connections at the same time. My reference to 'leaving the secondary account logged in' is not talking about a remote connection but a regular windows login.

I'm not trying to do anything more than choose which user that RDC connects as. Perhaps the problem is that I'm initiating that login with a right click and 'Connect with Remote Desktop Connection'. I'll try editing a .RDP dedicated to that workstation.

more soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was trying to achieve this via the RightClick from the 'Network' node. Working against the full RDC connection object provides all options i'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Short version is you can't have more than one user logged in remotely in native Windows 7.  You have to either use a third party application such as GoToMyPC or LogMeIn or the other user must be logged out.  If you were using a version of Windows Server you can have 2 people logged in (or purchase additional licenses to have more), but for the base Windows lineup (XP/Vista/7), it's limited to one person at a time with the functionality that Windows includes.  And even in that case, if someone were to log in locally to that machine, any remote users would be logged out.

Comment: I'm only trying for one at a time.  I just want to specify which one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives:

If you setup a VNC server you can take control of the active session from remote but be warned: it won't be as smooth as a VNC connection. e.g. I use UltraVNC.

I think you might also be able to use the built in remote support feature of windows.

How much of a hacker are you? It's possible in XP and Vista and presumably also W7 to circumvent the one login limit.